# Change the Font of UINavigationBar title

Tags: iphone, ios5, uibutton, uinavigationbar, uifont

i am having this code to show the button as the title of the navbar,and then in button code i write the code to change the font of the unbutton text label.but i didn't get the correct font version with the below code.

```
UIButton *titleButton = [[UIButton alloc]init];
titleButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[titleButton setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 170, 35)];
[titleButton setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",delegatee.selectedBook,delegatee.selectedChapter]forState:UIControlStateNormal];

titleButton.titleLabel.font =[UIFont fontWithName:@"Georgia" size:10.0f];
[titleButton addTarget:self action:@selector(ClickbtnChaperselection:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
self.navigationItem.titleView = titleButton;
```

iput georgia but i didn't get the correct font
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

for button :- `use in Navigation Title view , this is work IOS 4 and IOS 5` ,I use .....

```
  UIButton *titleButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];    
[titleButton setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 170, 35)];
[titleButton setTitle:@"dee"forState:UIControlStateNormal];

 UIFont *font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"A_Nefel_Sereke" size:21];
titleButton.titleLabel.font =font;

titleButton.titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
[titleButton addTarget:self action:@selector(ClickbtnChaperselection:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
self.navigationItem.titleView = titleButton;
```

I think you have problem in your font name ...  Please check

Comment: If think you have font probelm, please check your font name in your project

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
UIButton *titleButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];    
[titleButton setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 170, 35)];
[titleButton setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",delegatee.selectedBook,delegatee.selectedChapter]forState:UIControlStateNormal];

titleButton.titleLabel.font =[UIFont fontWithName:@"Georgia" size:10.0f];
[titleButton addTarget:self action:@selector(ClickbtnChaperselection:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
self.navigationItem.titleView = titleButton;
```

Comment: when i put label instead of button ,it changes the font.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just put a label instead of a button as the title ?

Here's code for a title label:

```
UILabel *titleView = (UILabel *)self.navigationItem.titleView;
if (!titleView)
  {
    titleView = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    [titleView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [titleView setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Georgia" size:10.0f]];

    [self.navigationItem setTitleView:titleView];
    [titleView release];
  }
titleView.text = title;
```

If you need it to be UIButton, it shouldn't be too hard to adjust the code to your needs.

Good luck !

Comment: haii,beca i need a click action for the title.but i put label and choked but there also it is not changing the uifont